# Не удаляется служба без InstallContext

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, service

Есть код который удаляет службу:

```
using (var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller())
{
   var Context = new InstallContext("log.log", null); // Создаёт .log файл и записывает туда данные по удалению службы
   serviceInstaller.Context = Context; // Записываем данные из контекста
   serviceInstaller.ServiceName = service; // Имя службы
   serviceInstaller.Uninstall(null); // Удаляем службу         
}
```

Вот такой лог получаю:

> Выполняется удаление источника EventLog Http_analyzer_v7_netfilter.
>   Предупреждение. Источник Http_analyzer_v7_netfilter не зарегистрирован
>   на локальном компьютере. Выполняется удаление службы
>   Http_analyzer_v7_netfilter из системы... Служба
>   Http_analyzer_v7_netfilter успешно удалена из системы.

**Вопрос**:

Почему служба не удаляется без инициализатора **InstallContext** ?

Если сделаю просто так:

```
using (var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller())
{
   serviceInstaller.ServiceName = service; // Имя службы
   serviceInstaller.Uninstall(null); // Удаляем службу         
}
```

То так не удаляется, можно ли сделать так чтобы без инициализатора спокойно удалилось, или же с инициализатором **InstallContext** но без записи данных. ( он всё выводит в консоль ещё )

Answer (score 0):

В принципе проблему решил данным способом:

```
var Context = new InstallContext(); // Инициализируем контекст
Context.Parameters.Add("LogToConsole", "False"); // Передаём параметр не показывать в консоли
serviceInstaller.Context = Context;
```

То так всё работает нормально, но если у вас есть более интересный способ решения, буду благодарен если поделитесь.